# Python: how to process a huge single-line file?

Tags: python, file, filesystems

I have a huge single-line file, containing space-separated words only. I would like to run some additional filtering on it. How to do it fast?

Currently I have the following code:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        words = str(line).split(' ')        

        for w in words:
            if is_allowed(w):
                another_file.write(w + " ")
```

But it is **extremelly slow** (~1Mb/s). How to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you describe the file as "huge", the problem is likely down to your code needing to load the entire file into memory at once, and then making a copy of it in order to carry out the split operation.

It ought to be much faster if you treat the file as a stream. Read it character by character (`char = f.read(1)`); if the character is anything other than a space or EOF, append it to a temporary string. When you hit a space, process your temporary string and then blank it and start over; when you hit EOF, process your temporary string and then break out of your loop.

That way you should never have more than a single word in memory at any given moment, which should vastly speed up your processing.